# where does redis ziplist save memory?

Tags: redis

I don't understand where does redis ziplist save so much memory;
a ziplist entry has structure as below

```
struct ZipListEntry{
  int prev_entry_bytes_length;
  int encoding;
  char* contents;
};
```

a common list node has structure as this

```
class ListNode{
   int prev;
   int next;
   int encoding;
   char* data;
};
```

compare both, **ListNode** just has one more member **next** than **ZipListEntry**, where does redis ziplist save memory so much? Is it because **ZipList's** memory are allocate for once so the memory is continuous while common **ListNode's** memory are allocated for several times which generates memory slices?

Comment: [This article](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-1-short-structures/9-1-1-the-ziplist-representation/) explains it well. In essence, the savings come from storing the ziplist as a single continuous array rather than having the overhead of multiple pointers for each entry.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry tks~